# MYSQL Convert join to subquery

Tags: mysql, join, sum, subquery

I'm try to convert a join query to not have the join and use subqueries only but for the life of me I can not figure out a way.

TABLES:

[image: TABLE1][image: TABLE2]

With these tables I'm trying to do the following: Using subqueries get the FirstName, LastName and registration paid of the attendees who have paid the most registration.

This query produces that result using a join.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, SUM(tblregistration.RegistrationPaid) AS `AmountPaid`
FROM tblregistration, tblattendees
WHERE tblregistration.AttendeeID = tblattendees.AttendeeID
GROUP BY tblregistration.AttendeeID 
ORDER BY `AmountPaid` DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

[image: Results]

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Why you don't like `JOIN`?  I can't see why you'd rather use a subquery here.

Comment: I do. But I'm required to for an assignment :(   I'm better with joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work :

```
SELECT
  (SELECT FirstName FROM tblattendees WHERE tblregistration.AttendeeID = tblattendees.AttendeeID) AS `FirstName`,
  (SELECT LastName FROM tblattendees WHERE tblregistration.AttendeeID = tblattendees.AttendeeID) AS `LastName`,
  SUM(tblregistration.RegistrationPaid) AS `AmountPaid`
FROM tblregistration
GROUP BY tblregistration.AttendeeID
ORDER BY `AmountPaid` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Didn't know you could work with the two tables like that within a select subquery.

Comment: Yes it is possible but it will probably be less efficient than the join version.

Comment: Yeah I have read in a few places that joins are generally faster and of course much easier and faster to write as well.

Comment: This is a corellated subquery. An uncorellated subquery is often faster, but it's pretty hard to write one without a JOIN somewhere ;-)